# how to write the same in less code. Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this method:

```
def get_user_info(self):

    month       = choice(range(1,13))
    day         = choice(range(1,29))
    year        = choice(range(1966,1994))  
    f_name      = self.assign_name('FirstNames')
    l_name      = self.assign_name('LastNames')
    e_address   = f_name+l_name+year.__str__()+day.__str__()
    password    = f_name+l_name+'0008383'

    user_info = dict({
            'month'     : month,
            'day'       : day,
            'year'      : year,

            'f_name'    : f_name,
            'l_name'    : l_name,
            'e_address' : e-address,
            'password'  : password
    })

    print user_info
```

It gives me the  right result, But I fill like I'm writing the same code twice. So my question is how to get the same result without first creating variables, and than put them into dict().

Note, I need to use f_name and l_name and so on in different key:value pairs.

Comment: To be honest, this is the wrong thing to be looking at for optimization.

Comment: Well, consider that in `{expr1 : expr2, ..}` (no `dict` is required here as `{}` does that already), `expr1` and `expr2` are both *arbitrary expressions*. They need not be string literals or variable names, which are two kinds of expressions themselves .. (It should therefor follow that `choice(range(1,13))`, which is also an expression, could be substituted as appropriate. However, I urge prudence in keeping side effects *out* of compound expressions.)

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oh thank you, I didn't know about codereview section

Comment: side note: don't call `__str__` directly, use `str(obj)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm inclined to think that, given the values you're computing, the way you're doing it now is more or less the best you can do. There are some small improvements, like skipping your call to `dict` and using the `str` built-in function rather than calling `__str__` methods directly, but there aren't really any good changes to make at a high level.

The reason is that you're using each of the first five of your variables at least twice. You use them once individually, as a value that's stored in the dictionary under their own key (e.g. the `f_name` value is stored as `user_info["f_name"]`), and you also use them to build up the values for `e_address` and/or `password`. While it would be possible to put those first five values directly into the dictionary, getting them out again for use in the other calculations requires code that is even more redundant than what you have now.

So, unless you want to change your `e_address` or `password` calculations to be independent of the other values, I'd stick with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're looking for refactoring the code or reducing the length.

If it's the latter, you can do multiple assignment and reduce lines.

So something like:

```
def get_user_info(self):

    month, day, year      = choice(range(1,13)) , choice(range(1,29)), choice(range(1966,1994))  
    f_name, l_name        = self.assign_name('FirstNames') , self.assign_name('LastNames')
    e_address, password   = f_name+l_name+year.__str__()+day.__str__(), f_name+l_name+'0008383'
```

And you don't really need to put in 'dict()', `{}` does that already!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the shortest you can do without sacrificing readability (but improving on [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compilance, for instance):

```
    def get_user_info(self):
        month = choice(range(1, 13))
        day = choice(range(1, 29))
        year = choice(range(1966, 1994))
        f_name = self.assign_name('FirstNames')
        l_name = self.assign_name('LastNames')
        print {'month' : month,
               'day' : day,
               'year' : year,
               'f_name' : f_name,
               'l_name' : l_name,
               'e_address' : f_name + l_name + str(year) + str(day),
               'password' : f_name + l_name + '0008383'}
```

As a side note, do reconsider your password generation policy, it's quite insecure in your code.

Also did you notice you've probably missed out `month` from `e_address` assignment?